# Send_keys function is not working in selenium -python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I use both xpath or css_selector to find element, it finded, it clicked, but it can not send_keys anyway.
I think the problem is input class when clicked and not clicked is different('_1y306T' and  '_1y306T _2ynKud' ).I tried use EC, sleep, but it fail.

HTML code:

```
<div class='UEclfJ _27cR_W'>
<input type ='tel' autocomplete='one-time-code' maxlength = '6'>

<input class='_1y306T _2ynKud' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
<input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
<input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
<input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
<input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>
<input class='_1y306T' maxlength = '1'reandonly value>

</div>
```

I tested first cell, It had 6 cell(OTP form)
My code:

```
        cell_change = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(lambda driver:self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@class, "_1y306T") and contains(@class, "_2ynKud")]'))
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly','readonly')", cell_change)
        print("remove success")
        sleep(3)
        cell_change.send_keys("1")
        sleep(1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think your issue because the input element having **readonly** attribute.

Comment: yeah I have thought about this, I tried remove this by execute_js and set value, its fails to confirm

Comment: The question is whether you can manually input text these elements? (by human, not selenium)

Comment: yes i can manually input

Comment: I removed "readonly" before send_keys, it change a bit, but still not appear char

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cell_change = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(lambda driver:self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@class, "_1y306T") and contains(@class, "_2ynKud")]'))
```

Comment: It still not works , it can be clicked but not be able to send_keys